# Selecting date_trunc function for column

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I just want to know if it's possible to use date_trunc function for postgresql? Because I have a table that contains time without time zone.

example: `SELECT date_trunc('hour', time 'columnName') from tableName`

Thank you so much! Keep safe everyone

Comment: The syntax is:  `date_trunc('hour', columnName)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr @GordonLinoff!!